# Assign a submitted Node to a Single User of Role Editor

Tags: workflows

I am building a content publishing website. There are users with different roles editors, authors, content managers. There are many users with each role. Now what needs to be done is to assign a node to a specific user with a role as an editor or you can say to a specific editor.

I am using workflow module which puts the article to a review state once it is submitted. Now what it does is it allows all of the user with a role as an editors to edit and review the node. But I want that it should only be assigned to one editor and that should be done by the content manager.

I can not get my head around how should this be done. Are there any modules available or I would need to write something myself?

Comment: Have you looked at the [Workbench](https://drupal.org/project/workbench) module and its submodules?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't test it, but the module's description seems to match your needs:

https://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess

Otherwise it can be done with a custom module: add a field "authorized editor" of type user reference to your content type, and then use the [node_access](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_access/7) function to grant access to the update operation to the user who is currently trying to edit it.